# After Upgrade to ubuntu 18.04 laptop screen was flickering

Tags: screen, flicker

[image]I am using Dell latitude 3580 model recently i upgrade Ubuntu 18 .After upgrade my laptop screen was flickering frequently i checked Hardware that's fine no issues .Any solution for this to fix ? i checked system software all up to date and also i tried ubuntu-drivers autoinstall all its says up to date.Guide me how to fix ?

Comment: Please post hardware specifications.

Answer (score 0):

i have also issue with screen flickering after updating Ubuntu, what solve the issue was to downgrade the kernel .